# NPC will not stop at a certain distance of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a NPC which follows my player but I cant get it to stop when it is at a certain distance from the player. This has been frustrating me all night as there is nothing on the web for doing this.

They collide and hit each other!

Here is my code for moving the NPC:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AI : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
public int moveSpeed = 5;
public int rotationSpeed = 2;
public Transform myTransform;

void Awake ()
{
    myTransform = transform;
}

void Start ()
{
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
}

void Update ()
{
    myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

}
}
```

Comment: put a trigger oval around your target and if the enemy goes through the trigger collider then stop the AI from moving. Use `OnTriggerEnter()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i cant get this to work as well as the code given to me below, do you know of any tutorials i can follow for this? new to Unity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only apply the movement code if it's to far away. If it's close enough then apply no movement code. ie update should be:

```
Vector3 Distance = target.position - myTransform.position;
if(Distance.sqrMagnitude>minDistance*minDistance)
{
    myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am new to Unity and C# and trying to understand this, but i can not get this to work! 
I need to make the minDistance exist in the context
Do i add this as a float? Appreciate your time!

Comment: i used

public float minDistance = 1f;

The object follows the character but only the player is really far away from the player, how can i fix this? sorry for the questions!